# MySQL - Como puedo editar los valores de una columna de precios con dos decimales?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla de phpmyadmin que tiene varios valores de precios con formato **varchar** y algunos tienen hasta 6 decimales.

Quiero que todos mis valores pasen a 2 decimales.

**Por ejm:**

```
ID - PRECIO
1 - 10.00
2 - 25.0365
3 - 25.03
4 - 36.3662


ID - PRECIO
1 - 10.00
2 - 25.04
3 - 25.03
4 - 36.34
```

Quisiera hacer un **UPDATE** y que todos mis valores pasen a ser 2 decimales.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Listo, solucioné con un recurso de stackoverflow en inglés

```
UPDATE t_products SET price = round(price,2)
```

Esta consulta SQL hace que se edite los valores unicamente y se redondee a 2 decimales.